# ios : push notification badge count not increase in this payload formate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications

When application in background that time badge count not set last 5 days before is working properly.
**Badge count every time increase by php backend ex. Current badge = 10 then after second push get then badge = 11**

I am using bellow payload formate.
If any change in bellow formate then help me i read also refer [Apple Push Notification Service.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

push notification payload is a JSON payload:

```
{
    "aps": {
         "badge": 10,
         "alert": "Hello world!",
         "sound": "cat.caf"
    }
}
```

registerUserNotificationSettings

```
if (ios8)
    {
        if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
            UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
        else
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
```

Comment: it seems fine have you checked via Pusher?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your issue : do you wand to badge to be set to 10 or do you want to increase it by 10 ? The title of your question in confusing.

Comment: Did you make sure to call `registerUserNotificationSettings` with the appropriate `UIUserNotificationType.Badge`?

Comment: @dbn refer that my updated question.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo badge count every time increase by php backend ex. Current badge = 10 then after second push get then badge = 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the description of payload keys from [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1), the value associated with the key badge must be a number, so you can't increment the badge value from the payload (otherwise you couldn't differentiate a incrementation or a badge set to 1).

You can save the badge value server side and increment in on the server, so it will looks like an incrementation for the user.

Comment: Yes, you are right badge must be number :)  my backend developer just change string to number.